# How to define flat object structure in swagger body parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm using swagger 2.0 and need to define a post request to create an account object. The object data is passed in the body as a flat object structure:

Example body data:

```
{
  first_name: "Sherlock",
  last_name: "Holmes",
  address: "Bakerstreet 221b",
  # tax_id: not set, # optional
}
```

When I create the request doc in yaml:

```
definitions:
  new_account:
    properties:
      first_name:
        type: string
      last_name:
        type: string
      address:
        type: string
      tax_id:
        type: string
    required:
      - first_name
      - last_name
      - address
paths:
  /accounts:
    post:
      summary: Create account
      parameters:
        - name: account
          in: body
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/new_account"
```

the documentation describes a body with exactly one element: `account` which itself contains some fields. However my structure is flat, no top node `account`.

If I leave out the `name` attribute, it's basically the same, only that the name column is empty in the resulting documentation and the whole structure is either required or not.

My current workaround is to list all parameters and set `in: query` but that's obviously wrong.

How to define this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`account` is just the name of the body parameter. One usage is in the method signature in the API client generated by [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). In other words, `account` is not a top node (FYI, in Swagger spec 1.2, the body parameter must be named `body`)

Your definition above is correct for the example body data you provided.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good to know because from the generated documentation this isn't obvious to me. I'd rather have all top elements listed, but if that's the correct way, I'll choose it.

Comment: So in Swagger 2 the name doesn't have to be `body` and it seems it's not mandatory at all. If I leave it out, it's also valid and may not confuse others by thinking that it's a top node name. What do you say?

Comment: Revert my last comment. Even though swagger editor shows parameter list without a name, it also shows an error that the definition in invalid. Looks like that's not an option and I would have to use `body` then to not confuse readers.